# Why shadow password hashed with sha512 contains 99 instead of 129 characters?

Tags: linux, pam

My Linux is configured to use `sha512`. Yet, the `/etc/shadow` file contains hashed password with 99 characters only. Why 99 and not 129 (64*2+1)? Note that I had changed password after making sure the system is set to use sha512.

Please see outputs:

```
# grep sha512 /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
# grep ENCRYPT_METHOD /etc/login.defs
ENCRYPT_METHOD SHA512
# grep root /etc/shadow
root:$6$YwkRWeVN$z4Z7OKuohyyT/4gZgnOkKSWPaMvx1eCHFGNCiyFZx1QYydrEArO.HdH2JGCfosXg0sTnZFFdJnfw5QgfUqovO1:16175:0:99999:7:::
```

Please notice that the password hash starts from `$6$` so it indicates that it is `sha512` hash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hash is stored in base64 format which means one charcter encodes 6 bits. So 512 / 6 = 86 (rounded up) characters are needed.

The hash starts after the third (not 2nd) $ and ends before next colon which is exactly 86 characters. The string `YwkRWeVN` between 2nd and 3rd $ is called [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Comment: Duh!!! I have not noticed that this is NOT a hex. I am humbled now!
Thank you so much for your explanation! That is exactly what I needed!